# Getting text selection with javascript, then modify text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a text on an HTML page. If the user selects a word, I can retrieve the selected word and know exactly what he or she selected. However, I now want to also modify this word on the screen and make it bold. But I do not know how I would do this, since I only know the word clicked, but do not see an easy way to find the word in the HTML and modify it. I could of course search for it, but there is the risk of a word appearing multiple times.

A different way I thought about would be to give each word a unique idea and have something like this:

```
<span id="1">The</span> 
<span id="2">fox</span> 
<span id="3">jumps</span> 
<span id="4">over</span> 
<span id="5">the</span> 
<span id="6">fence</span>
```

But I **do not like this solution**. This, too, seems overly complicated, does it not? Any suggestions **how else I could access the exact words selected**?

Comment: On click of the `<span>`, I would add a class to it (for example: strong), and in CSS make the strong class bold.

Comment: Do you also want the text to be bolded on double click, when selecting a single word? What about different parts of text being selected? e.g. The fox ju**mps over the fen**ce.

Comment: @RahulDesai well, the span solution is what i am trying to avoid!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can dynamically create a span surrounding the selected word:

```js
const p = document.querySelector('p');
p.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
  const range = document.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
  do {
    const charBefore = range.startContainer.textContent[range.startOffset - 1];
    if (charBefore.match(/\s/)) break;
    range.setStart(range.startContainer, range.startOffset - 1);
  } while (range.startOffset !== 0);
  do {
    const charAfter = range.endContainer.textContent[range.endOffset];
    if (charAfter.match(/\s/)) break;
    range.setEnd(range.endContainer, range.endOffset + 1);
  } while (range.endOffset !== range.endContainer.textContent.length);
  const span = document.createElement('span');
  span.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
  range.surroundContents(span);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>The fox jumps over the fence.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("p").mouseup(function() {

    var selection = getSelected().toString();

    $(this).html(function(){
        return $(this).text().replace(selection, '<strong>' + selection +'</strong>');
    });

});

var getSelected = function(){
    var t = '';
    if(window.getSelection) {
        t = window.getSelection();
    } else if(document.getSelection) {
        t = document.getSelection();
    } else if(document.selection) {
        t = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    return t;
}
```

```css
strong{ font-weight: bold; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>The fox jumps over the fence.</p>
```

Comment: I do **not** want to use spans, i just have plain text in a paragraph or div. Doing it with spans was the only solution I could think of, but it doesn't feel right. I think my question was maybe phrased a bit ambiguously

Answer (score 0):

No need of jQuery, also no need of IDs for each `<span>`.

The idea is to add a class to the span once it is clicked and later you can retrieve all elements with that bolded class.

Here is a solution with pure Javascript:

```
// comments inline
```

```js
var spans = document.getElementsByTagName('span'); // get all <span> elements

for(var i=0, l = spans.length; i<l; i++){
  spans[i].addEventListener('click', function(){ // add 'click' event listener to all spans
    this.classList.toggle('strong'); // add class 'strong' when clicked and remove it when clicked again
  });
}
```

```css
.strong {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<span>The</span> 
<span>fox</span> 
<span>jumps</span> 
<span>over</span> 
<span>the</span> 
<span>fence</span>
```

Read up: [`Element.getElementsByTagName()` - Web APIs | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName)

Comment: thank you. However, I do **not** want to use spans, - I just have plain text in a paragraph or div. I only gave the span example because it was the only solution I could think of, but it doesn't feel right. Or is this the only way to do this?